# Python Scripting Error (Adding a Field)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1

I'm using this code as a python script tool in ArcGIS 10.1:

```py
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.workspace = r'W:\S&P\s&p techs\Emily\Errors.gdb'

#Looping through dissolved feature classes, adding 'Name' field and writing
#feature class name in the added field.
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fcs:
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "Name", "TEXT", field_length = 50)
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "Name") as cursor:
      for row in cursor:
        row[0] = fc
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

All it's supposed to do is add a field to some feature classes in a database. I double checked that the path is right, so I don't think that's the problem. This code has also worked before, but for some reason it's not working anymore. I get an error that says this when I run it:

[image]

Comment: Convert your single quotes on your workspace line to double quotes.

Comment: Restart your ArcGIS Desktop(kill all desktop related processes) and try again, some times ArcGIS encounter some glitches like this. Your script is fine, though I suggest use `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["Name"])` fields list or tuple instead of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code works fine with single quote on my machine. I think it is something to do with gdb naming, (& character?). See if slightly modified code will help to track what's wrong

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy, traceback, os, sys
try:
    def showPyMessage():
        arcpy.AddMessage(str(time.ctime()) + " - " + message)
##    arcpy.env.workspace = r'W:\S&P\s&p techs\Emily\Errors.gdb'
    arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\URS-Data\URS-Data\From_MXD\Scratch.gdb'
    #Looping through dissolved feature classes, adding 'Name' field and writing
    #feature class name in the added field.
    fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    for fc in fcs:
        arcpy.AddMessage(fc)
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "Name", "TEXT", field_length = 50)
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "Name") as cursor:
          for row in cursor:
            row[0] = fc
            cursor.updateRow(row)
            break
except:
    message = "\n*** PYTHON ERRORS *** "; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Traceback Info: " + traceback.format_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])[0]; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Error Info: " +  str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"; showPyMessage()
```

Comment: Thanks @EmilyF. So what WAS wrong?